# Как включить отображение ошибок в консоле?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, nginx

На предыдущем хостинге, когда выполнялся какой-либо task и если вдруг при его работе возникала проблема (ошибка), то это сопровождалось краткой сводкой, включая конкретное место (файл) и строку.

Сейчас я переехал на другой хостинг и тут такого нет. После падения task есть единственное слово после:

> Killed

Как включить вывод мини-лога, как это было раньше? Ведь я теперь даже не знаю где искать... В файлах логов нет ничего по этому поводу.

Comment: Угадывать, что в теории может быть на хостинге, не очень интересно. Но похоже, что процесс убивается хостингом, нештатно, и потому вывести ничего не успевает, т. к. с его точки зрения всё ок.

Comment: @D-side это я взял капельку на DO. Настраивал все по их же статьям, они написаны очень подробно. Но сомневаюсь, что я что-то не так сделал в процессе настройки сервера, так как там делов на час, да и тупо копипаст.

Comment: Возможно, тупо кончилась оперативка, пришёл OOM-killer и всех поубивал без объяснений. Последите за показателями нагрузки системы в момент падения.

Comment: @D-side всего 512 Mb, сейчас рисует free пример 7-9 Mb. Как запустил task, то ОЗУ очистилась, а затем снова дошла до 7-9. Так и скачет в этом диапазоне с работающем task. А что касается самого сайта, то он упал. на сайте срабатывает заглушка publick/500.html. Короче говоря это ОЗУ?

Comment: @D-side сайт упал, зато теперь task не падает. Видать сейчас сервер тянет что-то одно. Не знаете, сколько нужно для нормальной работы Rails приложения с 2-4 одновременно запущенными task?

Comment: 500 обычно просто так не срабатывает. Её детали уж всяко должны быть в логах. Heroku утверждает, что аккуратно спроектированное приложение вполне может уместиться в 512-метровой машине в количестве 2-4 воркеров. Рассмотрите возможность запустить воркер в том же процессе, например. Или хотя бы чтобы он форкался и делил общие участки с основным процессом.

Comment: @D-side до тех пор, пока я не начал запускать task, сам сайт работал отлично. Шустро. Ну и сам сайт по моим только что наблюдениям занимает при запуске примерно 300 Mb в ОЗУ. А как только запускается task, то она как бы вытесняет сайт и шлет его куда подальше. Вот он и загибается. Что касается воркеров, когда настраивал Puma, то сервер мне сообщил, что у меня только 1 воркер.

Comment: @D-side опять же, настраивал nginx-puma-rails по статье на DO, под ubuntu. В гугле она одна такая, можете найти без труда (в первых ссылках).

Comment: @D-side вырубил сейчас task, сайт заработал. task у меня парсит сайт. То есть там полноценная прогулка по странице, выборка, запись в локальную для сайта БД.

Comment: Возможно, стоит вытащить её в отдельную капельку и соединить с той же базой по сети. Хотя бы падать будет отдельно %) Тут уж кто на что горазд, есть куча направлений для решения.

Comment: @D-side как вариант, но платить 5 баксов за task'и :)

Comment: Ну, производительность не берётся из ниоткуда. Что написано неэффективно или делает очень много, будет требовать много ресурсов :) Поищите ещё на предмет возможности подкачку добавить, например.

Comment: @D-side с файлом подкачки это вы просто охерительно подсказали. Благо на капельках SSD стоят, сделал 4 Gb. Проверил сейчас - вроде пашет все. Чувствуется, что слегка медленней происходит загрузка страниц, но все же это лучше, чем ничего. Великолепно! Огромное спасибо в очередной раз!

Comment: @D-side добавьте в свой ответ про файл подкачки еще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Никак.

#### Потому что с точки зрения приложения всё в порядке.

#### А вот с точки зрения ОС — не очень.

Симптомы очень похожи на **нехватку оперативной памяти** (никакого вывода и одинокий `killed` после завершения). Когда памяти остаётся критически мало, срабатывает [OOM-killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer), который по отфонарному алгоритму грохает какой-нибудь работающий процесс, чем освобождает занятые им ресурсы. **Это нештатная ситуация**, при нормальной работе она не должна возникать вообще, и если возникает, нужно принимать меры.

Решить это можно всего одним способом: предотвратив нехватку оперативки. Либо расширив доступный объём (необязательно именно физической ОЗУ, **можно и подкачкой**) , либо снизив её потребление, на ваш выбор.

Comment: Вас понял. Проблема возникает из-за конфликта проекта, который лежит в ОЗУ с task, которая запускается параллельно. Воркер у меня 1. Можно как-нибуь решить проблему кроме апгрейда железки, так как таски в моем проекте очень важны?

Comment: @Colibri снижать любыми способами потребление ОЗУ отдельных компонентов. Можно даже попытаться их соединить, запуская таски в тредах процесса вебсервера. Так дублирования точно не станет, но если упадёт, то целиком. Можно ещё попробовать при запуске таски форкаться от вебсервера (запускать таску прдиётся откуда-то изнутри), так дублирования (Ruby 2.0+) будет всё же поменьше чем у самостоятельного запуска. Так хотя бы будет шанс, что упадёт только таска, а не вся система.